# What to do when there is a minor but crucial typo in a post, where fixing it is too short for an edit suggestion?

Tags: support, editing

What should I do when there is a minor but crucial typo in a post (perhaps of literally one character) that is otherwise perfect?

Occasionally I come across a question or answer that is perfect other than literally only one or two characters in the body wrong. I can’t recall a precise one as of now, but as a hypothetical example, suppose an answer to a question contained the text

> ...since the discriminant of the quadratic $ax^2+bx+c$ is $b^3-4ac$...

This is of course a crucial mistake, probably just a typo, that’d could confuse someone who is learning this. I’d want to suggest an edit where that $3$ should be changed to a $2$.

The issue is, that edit is only one character, and there’s a minimum length for edits before it’ll let you suggest one (I believe its 6 or 10 or 12 characters or something like that). Usually I can mess about with something else - perhaps there is some grammatical error, or I can add some clarity, or remove something unnecessary, or whatever. But what if the post is otherwise perfect? What to do?

Comment: You can either leave a comment and hope that someone else will fix it, or you can make the edit and clean up any other problems as you go (nothing is perfect---you can probably find other typos which need correction).

Comment: Welcome to Math Meta. FYI, in the "Related" section on the right, there's [Minimum suggested edit length](/q/2216/602049) where, although it's from more than $12$ years ago, its answers nonetheless may be of some interest, & use, to you regarding your question. Also, as stated in the "Is there a minimum change threshold for a suggested edit?" section of the [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76284) to "How do suggested edits work?" in the network Meta FAQ question, "Yes, all suggested edits that modify the body in any way must **change at least six characters in the post body**".

Comment: You can always add something to make the question more understandable or perhaps make it look good by changing formatting, spaces etc..